# How can I parse a string into individual words and sort them in Java?

Tags: java

I am trying to have a user input a line of text and then be able to reorder it.  I do not understand how to be able to seperate each word from the input text to be able to use substring and reorder. I don't know how to use array and only have two weeks experience in programming.

Comment: @Bhushan: How did this Java question suddenly become a Javascript one?

Comment: I see that @JohnFx changed the title to mention Javascript instead of Java... Is there a reason to think this *is* about Javascript?

Comment: That was a mistake. Sorry, Fixing it.

Comment: @aix: at that time the title said "...and sort them in Javascript"

Answer (score 3):

> I do not understand how to be able to seperate each word from the input text

If `inputStr` is your input string, you can use

```
String[] words = inputStr.split("\\s+");
```

This will create an array called `words` and would populate it with the (space-separated) words of the input string.

`String.split()` is explained [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29). If you haven't come across regular expressions, the `"\\s+"` simply means "one or more spaces".

Answer (score 0):

If you mean JavaScript, not Java, the syntax is a little different from JavaScript

```
var words = inputStr.replace(/\s+/g, ' ').split(' ');
```

Where `inputStr.replace(/\s+/g, ' ')` replaces 1+ whitespaces with 1 whitespace, and `split(' ')` splits the whitespace delimited string into an array.

Then you can reorder the array based on what you want.

You want to make the reordered array into a string again, use:

```
var newString = words.join(' ');
```

Answer (score 0):

aix's suggesting to use a regex to split gets the string parsed into an array which has a sort method in javascript.

```
s = "zero apple watchdog hammer";
s.split( " " ).sort();
```

...should produce the array...

```
["apple", "hammer", "watchdog", "zero"]
```

Its not too different in Java...

```
String s = "zero apple watchdog hammer";
String[] splits = s.split( " " );
Arrays.sort( splits );
System.out.println( String.format( "splits: %s", Arrays.toString( splits ) ) );
```

Of course, the regex passed to split can be improved to handle all manner of whitespace. I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader.